# Cashflow diagram in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

A cashflow diagram is often used when explaining derivatives in financial engineering.  It shows the payoffs at different times.  I couldn't find a great example online, but it looks something like this:

[image]

I would like to make something roughly equivalent using `ggplot2`.  My thought was to use a stacked [bar plot](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_bar.html), where the zero axis is somewhere in the middle.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Here's some example data:

```
data.frame(time=c(1, 2, 3), positive=c(5, 0, 4), negative=c(-2, 0, 0))
```

*Edit:*

Thanks to Hadley's answer; the resulting image looks like:

[image]

With boxes it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one attempt.

```
ggplot(df, aes(time, xend = time)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(y = 0, yend = positive, colour = "positive"),
    position = "stack", arrow = arrow()) + 
  geom_segment(aes(y = 0, yend = negative, colour = "negative"), 
    position = "stack", arrow = arrow()) + 
  scale_colour_manual("Direction", 
    values = c("negative" = "red", "positive" = "black"))
```

But I think you really need to stack the values yourself, because you don't get quite enough control with ggplot2.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks Hadley.  I actually wanted "bars" even though I wasn't clear about that, but I just changed your solution to use `geom_rect` and it works!  `ggplot(df, aes(time, xend = time)) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=time, xmax=time+1, ymin = 0, ymax = positive, fill = "positive")) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=time, xmax=time+1, ymin = 0, ymax = negative, fill = "negative")) + 
  scale_fill_manual("Direction", 
    values = c("negative" = "red", "positive" = "black"))`

Answer (score 1):

I suggested this to Khanh once for [RQuantLib](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RQuantLib).  This could now be *your* first patch :)

One issue, I think, is that you may not want full axis on either side -- long-dated zeros would have too little on the x-axis, and for standard bonds the different payout between coupons and par amount would likely look odd too.

Then again, this is R and `fortune("yoda")` still applies.

Comment: Neat idea.  Let's see what we come up with and then think about the patch.